# Calculating grand total from multiple tables using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have four dynamically generated tables, and each has a cell where I calculate the sum of cells in that column  - like this:

```
  <td id="sum1"></td>
  <td id="sum2"></td>
  <td id="sum3"></td>
  <td id="sum4"></td>
```

The way I calculate these sums is through a SWITCH statement, depending on what users select from a drop down:

```
  <select id="switch_options">
     <option value="1">Option1</option>
     <option value="2">Option2</option>
     <option value="3">Option3</option>
     <option value="4">Option4</option>
   </select>
```

As users select different options from the drop-down and enter some additional data into a text field, I am building the tables above dynamically and I calculated the sum like this:

```
     switch(switch_options)
     {
     case "1":
      //generate table1

      $( '#table1> tbody:last' )
        .hide()
        .append( "<tr><td>" + data.food_name + "</td>" + "<td class=amount>"
          + data.food_amount + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.food_serving + "</td>" 
          + "<td>" + data.protein + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.fats + "</td>" 
          + "<td>" + data.carbs + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.sugar + "</td>" 
          + "<td class=cal_bk>" + calories + "</td>" 
          + "<td><img class=delete src=images/del.jpg /></td></tr>" )
        .fadeIn( 'slow' );      

     //Calculate totals for table1
     calculateSumbk();
        function calculateSumbk() {
          $('#table1').each(function(){
            // iterate through 'cal' cells in each row:
            $("td.cal_bk").each(function() {
                bk_sum += parseInt($(this).text());
            }); 
            $("#sum1").html(bk_sum);                            
          }); 
        }

     case "2":
      //generate table2, etc.
```

I have a separate table where I'd like to calculate the grand totals of all the other tables, in a cell like this:

```
    <td id="totals"></td>
```

Problem is I don't seem to find an easy way to do it - the fact that I calculate the totals for each table under it's corresponding switch statement seems to be in the way.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: OK, problem solved, I used JQuery Calculation plugin and it works great.

Comment: For the benefit of other people reading this question in the future, please can you add your own solution to the question.  (It's okay to answer your own question.)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var qty = $(this).val();

// get the price cell by moving up a level and searching for
// the descendant with a class name beginning with `price'.
// Remove the dollar sign to do math
var price = $(this).closest("tr")
                   .find("td[class^=price]")
                   .html().split("$")[1];

// a quantity is a whole number but a price is a float
var total = parseInt(qty) * parseFloat(price);

// write the total for this book to the 'total' cell
$(this).closest("tr")
       .find("td[class^=total]")
       .html("$" + total);

// sum up all the totals
var grandTotal = 0;
$("td[class^=total]").each(function() {
    grandTotal += parseFloat($(this).html().split("$")[1]); 
});

// update the grandtotal cell to the new total
$(".grandtotal").html("$" + grandTotal);
});​
```

In other words, you need to:

1 - Get the quantity from the selected option's value.

2 - Get the price from the cell in the same row whose class begins with '**price**', multiply that by the quantity, and update the 'total' cell of the same row.

3 - (Re)calculate the grand total (the sum of all totals) and put that value into the `.grandtotal cell.`

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kYssr/4/